# Selenium/Beautiful Soup scraper failing after looping through one page (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape data on food seasonality from the Seasonal Food Guide but hitting a snag. The site has a fairly simple URL structure:

https://www.seasonalfoodguide.org/produce_name/state_name

I've been able to use `Selenium` and `Beautiful Soup` to successfully scrape the seasonality information from one page, but on subsequent loops the section of text I'm looking for doesn't actually load so I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`. I know it's because `months_list_raw` is coming back empty due to the fact that the `'wheel-months-list'` portion of the page isn't loading on the second loop. Code is below. Any ideas?

```
for ingredient in produce_list:
    for state in state_list:

        # grab page content
        search_url = 'https://www.seasonalfoodguide.org/{}/{}'.format(ingredient,state)
        driver.get(search_url)
        page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

        # grab list of months
        months_list_raw = page_soup.find('p',{'id':'wheel-months-list'})
        months_list = months_list_raw.text
```

Comment: Did you verify that the page (food/state combination) it is trying to load actually exists when it breaks? It seems like the error is that the html object doesn't exist for some pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is being rendered on the client side, which means when you open the page, another request is being made to a backend server to fetch the data based on your selected filters. So the issue is that when you open the page and read the HTML, the content is not fully loaded yet. The simplest thing you could do is sleep for some time after opening the page with Selenium in order to wait for it to fully load. I've tested your code by throwing in `time.sleep(3)` after the `driver.get(search_url)` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the error from occuring and continuing with your loop you need to do a check for when the `months_list_raw` element is not `None`. It seems like some of the produce pages do not have any data for some states, so you will need to handle that in your program how you want.

```
for ingredient in produce_list:
    for state in state_list:
        # grab page content
        search_url = 'https://www.seasonalfoodguide.org/{}/{}'.format(ingredient,state)
        driver.get(search_url)
        page_soup = soup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

        # grab list of months
        months_list_raw = page_soup.find('p',{'id':'wheel-months-list'})
        if months_list_raw is not None:
            months_list = months_list_raw.text
        else:
            # Handle case where ingredient/state data doesn't exist
```

Comment: This wasn't the root cause of the issue I was flagging, but it is something that I forgot to add. Thanks for calling it out